# Cannot access S3 through Java Code. [But can through AWS CLI]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, credentials

I cannot access `S3` through Java Code, but can through AWS `CLI`.

I am using Credentials from [AWS SDK for MINIO](https://docs.min.io/docs/aws-cli-with-minio.html)

```
// import statements

public class S3Application {

    private static final AWSCredentials credentials;
    private static String bucketName;

    static {
        //put your accesskey and secretkey here
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F",
                "zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG"
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //set-up the client

        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://play.min.io:9000","us-east-1"))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();

        AWSS3Service awsService = new AWSS3Service(s3Client);


    }

}
```

This is my log for the above mentioned code.

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
>           ...
>       Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>          ...
>           ... 13 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You have might have to set PathStyle access to true.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Builder.html#withPathStyleAccessEnabled-java.lang.Boolean-

Code like this might work.

```
// import statements

public class S3Application {

    private static final AWSCredentials credentials;
    private static String bucketName;

    static {
        //put your accesskey and secretkey here
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F",
                "zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG"
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //set-up the client

        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://play.min.io:9000","us-east-1"))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                .build();

        AWSS3Service awsService = new AWSS3Service(s3Client);


    }

}
```